# Role.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, associations

I'm trying to refer a foreign key between 2 models. but I'm getting this error:

throw new Error(${this.name}.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model); ^ Error: Role.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

**User model**

```
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize';

import sequelizeConnection from '~/configs/connectDB';
import { IUserAttributes, IUserInput } from '~/interfaces/user.interface';
import Role from './Role.model';

class User extends Model<IUserAttributes, IUserInput> implements IUserAttributes {
  public id!: number;
  public username!: string;
  public email!: string;
  public password!: string;
  public roleId!: number;

  public readonly createdAt!: Date;
  public readonly updatedAt!: Date;
}

User.init(
  {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
    },
    email: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    username: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    password: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    roleId: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    sequelize: sequelizeConnection,
    underscored: false,
  },
);

User.belongsTo(Role, {
  foreignKey: 'roleId',
  as: 'role',
});

export default User;
```

**Model Role**

```
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize';

import sequelizeConnection from '~/configs/connectDB';
import { IRoleAttributes, IRoleInput } from '~/interfaces/role.interface';
import User from './User.model';

class Role extends Model<IRoleAttributes, IRoleInput> implements IRoleAttributes {
  public id!: number;
  public roleName!: string;
  public key!: 'R1' | 'R2' | 'R3';

  public readonly createdAt!: Date;
  public readonly updatedAt!: Date;
}

Role.init(
  {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
    },
    roleName: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    key: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING(10),
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    sequelize: sequelizeConnection,
    underscored: false,
  },
);

Role.hasMany(User, {
  foreignKey: 'roleId',
});

export default Role;
```

Does someone have already see an error that look like that ? I search for few days without any issue, if someone could help I'll really appreciate,

thank !

Comment: You just need to exclude importing one model in another model's module and define associations in a separate module when all models will be already initialized